# Print just a Rectangle Box from a Access Form through VBA

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a form with multiple tabs, it has a receipt in the first tab in a rectangle box. Is there a way to just print that rectangle box using VBA?

Comment: You can use the `DisplayWhen` property.

Comment: Or you could create a report that mimics that box, and print that report via vba